# How do I find a Neo4j node using an indexed property, across all types?

Tags: neo4j

I am storing a unique identifier for every node using a property named "uid".  This property is maintained across all types.  However, GraphDatabase.findNode(...) requires that you pass in a non-null value for "label".  So, how do I do a cross-type find?

The only thing that I can think of is to execute a cypher query to do this.

Comment: How do you create a value for this uid property ?

Comment: For testing purposes, I created a node using the cypher statement: CREATE (n:TEST {uid: "test"})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two options here:

1) Create a new "super" label that all nodes have and create your index on this label.

2) Use a manual index

**1. "Super" label**

Since nodes can have multiple labels you can create a new label that acts a super label that all nodes have. Then create a schema index on the `uid` property on *that* label and query it.

For example, let's say you currently have the node labels `User` and `Customer` and you want to do an indexed lookup for the node where the `uid` property is `123` across both node labels. Create a new label `Person` on all nodes that have either `User` or `Customer` label:

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE any(x in labels(a) WHERE x IN ["User", "Customer"])
SET a:Person;
```

Now create an index on `:Person(uid)`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(uid);
```

Since this is a unique identifier it should really have a uniqueness constraint (which will create an index):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.uid IS UNIQUE;
```

And search this new schema index:

```
MATCH (p:Person {uid: "123"})
RETURN p
```

or since you are the Java API:

```
Node person = graphdb.findNode("Person", "uid", "123")
```

**2. Manual Index**

Since you are using the Java API you also have the option of [creating a manual index](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#indexing):

```
// Create index
IndexManager index = graphdb.index();
Index<Node> people = index.forNodes("people");

// Add nodes to index
Node user1 = graphdb.createNode();
user1.setProperty("uid", "123");

// Search index
IndexHits<Node> hits = people.get("uid", "123");
Node user123 = hits.getSingle();
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is very helpful.  A follow-up question: what would your opinion be about the following approach: configure an auto index on the field "uid", and then use .execute(...) to lookup a node via the query "MATCH (n {uid: {uid}}) RETURN n".  Is that an anti-pattern?

Comment: Sure that should work. Auto index essentially registers a transaction handler to add nodes to the manual index. However you'll have to use a [START clause](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/cypher/clauses/start/) to search the manual index from Cypher. Personally, I would use the "super" label approach with a constraint to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Another follow-up question:  I found a reference for using an auto index that suggests that the index name for the START clause is "node_auto_index", and that the property name is passed as the argument.  However, when I try this from my neo4j browser, it reports "Index `node_auto_index` does not exist", what am I missing?

Comment: For testing purposes, I created a node using the cypher statement: CREATE (n:TEST {uid: "test"})

Comment: Actually, my mistake on the auto-index configuration, I edit'd neo4j.conf and not neo4j.properties...*sigh*

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that auto-indexing is not the way to go, and is in fact considered a legacy feature, I will do this using your suggestion #1 above.